# How to use a callback as watch expression in an angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to use a callback function in my angular `context-menu` directive to trigger a watch. Unfortunately watch expression is never evaluated.

Any ideas what's missing?

For the full source code see http://plnkr.co/edit/PAjuvztuM8vlZ1U54XSy .

Directive:

```
    app.directive("contextMenu", function($log) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          scope.$watch(
            function() { return scope.$eval(iAttrs.openOnTrigger); },
            function() { $log.debug('context-menu check open:', scope.$eval(iAttrs.openOnTrigger))}
          )
        }
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch is not evaluated because nothing is triggering a digest cycle that would evaluate it. Because you bind click events with JQuery, angular doesn't really know about them. In this case you need to manually trigger a digest cycle with $apply (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

for example:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.onRightClick();
 })
```

modified Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vELZQbBLOTv4Z5YdfH7K

Comment: Thanks! Good spot!